# SSL and mixed content due to CSS background images

Tags: css, url, ssl, image, https

I have a web page containing am entry form. HTTPS is enabled via an Apache redirect for all requests matching that page. Unfortunately, because the CSS pulls in external images using  'background-image: url(/images/...)', the browser will generate a warning message that the page contains mixed content.

What's the best way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 31):

> Update 2014.12.17:
>
> Now that SSL is [encouraged for everyone](https://www.eff.org/encrypt-the-web-report) and [doesn’t have performance
>   concerns](https://istlsfastyet.com/), **this technique is now an anti-pattern**. If the asset you > need is available on SSL, then always use the `https://` asset.
>
> Allowing the snippet to request over HTTP opens the door for attacks
>   like the [recent Github Man-on-the-side attack](http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2015-03&post=China%27s-Man-on-the-Side-Attack-on-GitHub). It’s **always** safe to
>   request HTTPS assets even if your site is on HTTP, however the reverse
>   [is not true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content).
>
> More guidance and details in [Eric Mills’ guide to CDNs & HTTPS](https://github.com/konklone/cdns-to-https#conclusion-cdns-should-redirect-to-https).

Source: [Paul Irish – The Protocol-relative URL](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)

---

Here is a very popular solution:

There's this little trick you can get away with that'll save you some headaches:

## In HTML

```
<img src="//domain.com/img/logo.png">
```

## In CSS

```
div{background: url(//path/to/image.png);}
```

Answer (score 9):

You should also enable HTTPS for your static resources, and then make sure that the `<link>` refers explicitly to the HTTPS url for the CSS resource (whose relative urls will then be interpreted relative to the HTTPS base of the CSS file).

Answer (score 1):

You should use full URL for your image:

```
https://your.domain.com/img/image.png`
```

or

```
https://your.domain.com/route/to/img/image.png
```

This solved my problem some time ago.