# What exactly are the rules for avoiding the "mixed content" warning in IE due to background images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, https

This is related to [SSL and mixed content due to CSS background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548551/ssl-and-mixed-content-due-to-css-background-images) but that question had no accepted answer and the one I'm asking is a little more specific.

Under some circumstances when accessing an HTTPS website, IE will throw the "mixed content" warning if an element is given a style with a background image. I found [one forum reference](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=38342&st=0&p=212538&#entry212538&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFrqEzdoStGPB3vBUxYPdNjB4AGB7G9umw) that said the warning can be avoided if you put the reference in a stylesheet, for example

```
#someElement a {
    width:11px;
    height:11px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url(../images/sprites_list.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:hand;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-position:0px -72px;
}
```

but not if you try to create the element inline, a la

```
$('#someElement').append("<a title='something' style='background: url(../images/sprites_list.png) no-repeat; ... // etc
```

and indeed, this works for me. I've seen others that say you have to use an absolute `https` URL to refer to the image, rather than a relative one.

What is the real story here? Is there some "official" explanation or at least a reference to what the rules are? Or failing that, is there a standard set of guidelines which if followed makes it extremely unlikely to trigger the warning?

Comment: You can use a relative protocol as well: http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into that. But I really need relative URLs because this is a static CSS file and doesn't "know" the absolute URL base for the rest of my static content.

Comment: FYI, the protocol-relative URL _won't_ work around this particular IE8 bug if you're setting background-image through JavaScript. You _must_ use the full URL -- including the scheme and host -- to avoid the IE8 mixed content warning when doing JS style manipulations. (`element.style.backgroundImage = "//example.com/foo.png"` will warn.) <sigh>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the fully-qualified URI will avoid the problem of IE8 and below incorrectly creating a bogus URI like about:/relative/file.png that triggers the mixed content warning. This problem was fixed in IE9.

Comment: Thanks this is the answer I am looking for. But what exactly is `about:relative`? I haven't heard of that before. Btw nice job with Fiddler - it's a lifesaver in my IE 7 and 8 testing.

Comment: I think the "relative" was just Eric's pseudocode for some arbitrary relative path. So, you type in "/path/to/file.ext", and I guess IE turns that into "about:/path/to/file.ext", which is obviously stupid.

Comment: @Tom is correct. The problem is that the relative URIs are getting combined with a temporary about:blank markup. So, about:blank + /path/to/file.ext yields about:/path/to/file.ext, which is incorrectly treated as insecure.

Comment: I am currently getting the same problem. but it occurs very randomly. I am unable to diagnose the issue. I checked with fiddler, and there isn't any such call `about:blank` or `about:relative`. any clues?

Comment: @ZainShaikh, you won't be able to catch these with fiddler -- about: is an internal page that's fully resolved within the browser. Having just been through this myself, try combing your CSS for any relative urls, and your JavaScript for any style manipulations that don't use fully qualified urls. (e.g., something like `$('.foo').css('background-image', '//example.com/foo.png')` would cause this problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you're getting different results is not because the one method is "safer," but because the offending URL isn't present in the base document when IE loads it. I expect you'll get the warning if you were to place that `A` directly in the document instead of scripting it in after the page has loaded.

If I'm right in my diagnosis, this would mean there's no as-yet-undocumented quirk to the rules about mixed content.

Also: protocol-relative URLs are awesome. Just in general.

Comment: So, the rule is that I can't add new references to inline content on the fly, even if those links are under HTTPS? If that's the rule, I might be able to live with it, but I'd like some confirmation. Also, if that's the rule, why doesn't it affect ordinary `<img>` tags that I add to my HTML?

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say you shouldn't do it. I just think that explains the differing behavior you're seeing. Reading your comment to 65Fbef05, I am a little perplexed.

Answer (score 0):

After countless hours of the same problem, I couldn't figure out the problem. I then began picking through my source code and I found it. I'm using HTML5, and I'm using a shiv inside of a conditional comment to make HTML5 elements work in IE8 and down.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

My issue was that IE8 and down was throwing an error. That issue was solved by changing the above into a https, with the following:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="https://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

I haven't tested it, but I imagine the following might work too.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

It might save somebody down the road. If not, then good luck!