# Facebook comments widget over HTTPS/SSL security warning in IE7 & IE8

Tags: ssl, https, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, facebook-comments

I am attempting to add the Facebook comments widget to a page that is being served over SSL/HTTPS. The widget works fine, but when I attempt to load the page in IE7 or IE8, I get a "mixed content" Security Warning.

I've gone through and verified that we are not referencing any insecure resources in the page. Removing the facebook comments widget makes the warning disappear. Using fiddler, I tried to pinpoint the resource that is being referenced, but as far as I could see, nothing is being pulled over http. I've confirmed the issue with a minimal repro case that just has the comments widget on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>
      Test FB Comments
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.example.com/fb_minimal.html" data-num-posts="10" data-width="470" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'MY_FACEBOOK_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true,
          xfbml: true
        });
      };
      (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      } ());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This loads without warning in other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE9 and above).

I've reviewed my facebook application settings and everything appears to be configured correctly, although I am new to facebook integration, so perhaps I've missed something.

I've looked at this thread, [Facebook JavaScript SDK over HTTPS loading non-secure items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212016/facebook-javascript-sdk-over-https-loading-non-secure-items), but none of the suggestions there had any effect. I suspect this issue is different, since I'm not seeing warnings in other browsers as well.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're doing everything right, even checking the requests using Fiddler. Definitely very frustrating when you still can't see what's happening.

I don't have a definitive answer for you, but I can suggest one possibility

IE8 and below have been known to throw errors like this when it has a blank page in an iframe. eg the frame is created using javascript but doesn't have any content loaded, or is populated with `about:blank` as a URL.

I have a feeling it might also happen if you have content with errors (eg 404 errors), but I'm less certain about that. It's definitely a known bug with blank content.

What happens is that when IE is validating the security of the page, it incorrectly combines relative URLs in your page with the `about:blank` URL, resulting in URLs like `about:/myimage.jpg`, and it then sees that as being outside the HTTPS secure zone, and thus you get mixed content warnings.

You can see another discussion of this bug here: [What exactly are the rules for avoiding the "mixed content" warning in IE due to background images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961760/what-exactly-are-the-rules-for-avoiding-the-mixed-content-warning-in-ie-due-to)

The solution described there is to make all your URLs absolute URLs, with the complete domain and protocol included.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wasn't aware of this issue with IE8 before. It seems plausible that this might be the cause, but if it's Facebook's code that's creating the empty iFrame, I'm not sure if there is anything I can do about it. I'll have a look though.